# How to create a Text Channel in Discord Using JDA: Java Discord Api

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

```
 event.getGuild().createTextChannel("EzDedline_Reminder")
```

I have used this command for creating a text channel however the Text channel does get created.
I have given the bot administrative powers and added an event listener in the main function and have extended the listener adapter as well.

I do have the power to manage the channel as I am the owner of server.

Moreover, the code after this line is executing perfectly just this line of code is not able to create a new text channel.

event is the command entered by the user to run this function.

I am using JDA 4.2.1

Comment: Remember to mark the solution as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `queue()`.

```java
event.getGuild().createTextChannel("ezdedline_reminder").queue();
```

See [Nothing happens when using X](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19%29-Troubleshooting#nothing-happens-when-using-x) and [What is a RestAction?](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7%29-Using-RestAction).

Comment: .complete() if you it synchronized (wait the operation to finish before continuing).